# In C# Excel Interop whats Difference between new Excel.Workbook() and default(Excel.Workbook)

Tags: c#, com-interop, excel-interop

In C# Excel Interop what is is the difference between declaring `new Excel.Workbook()` and `default(Excel.Workbook)`.

Example:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objExcelWbk = new Excel.Workbook(); 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objExcelWbk = default(Excel.Workbook);
```

When I use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objExcelWbk = new Excel.Workbook();`it gives me the error **Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00020819-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}**

But when I use  `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook objExcelWbk = default(Excel.Workbook);` my script runs fine.

What are the guidelines for the use of each? And what are the differences?

Comment: The `new Excel.Workbook()` actually creates an instance of `Workbook` class. The `default(Excel.Workbook)` returns `null` since that's the *default* value for reference types.

Comment: @erdinger how to create a workbook that doesn't throw error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a workbook that way. The usual way to do it is

```
var objExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
var objExcelWbk = objExcelApp.Workbooks.Add();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186

Comment: How to open an Excel Workbook?

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly instantiating a workbook with its default values, versus instantiating an excel workbook via default constructor.

`default` is a keyword, the documentation can be found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx